# Calling module-level functions from destructor in D (seems to throw an OutOfMemoryError)

Tags: d

I have a global D module which contains some helper functions (namely for logging), which are at module-level and not in a class. However, when calling these functions from a destructor, I get a core.exception.OutOfMemoryError and/or the app hangs and crashes. Am I doing something wrong here?

A stripped-down test case:

logger.d

```
module main.logger;
void log(const(char)[] msg) {
    auto time = // GET TIME OF DAY SOMEHOW
    std.stdio.writeln(std.conv.to!string(time) ~ " " ~ msg);
}
```

class.d

```
module main.class;
import main.logger;

class A {
    public:
        this() {}
        ~this() { log("Destructor"); }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are; you're posting a vague question without providing a minimal testcase to reproduce the error. No offense.

Comment: I can whip up a small test case right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The garbage collector currently does not support thrown exceptions or memory allocations called from within a finalizer. Thus, you can't reliably do anything which causes an allocation or throws an uncaught exception from inside a class destructor.

Comment: That would make sense, assuming that writeln might have some background allocations going on.

Comment: @Mark string concatenation in log function is allocation too